# Printing multiple pages in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I'm trying to print (via a printer) two or more div's, each to its own page. I'm trying out different plugins, including printArea. 
I've tried something along the lines of :

```
this.$el.find(".print").map(function () {
  $(this).printArea();
});
```

in Chrome it brings up the print dialog twice, once for each div, but in Firefox, it just prints the last div. (Granted, I'm printing to a file instead of via a printer...) 
Showing the dialog twice is acceptable, though it would be nice to break it into two pages beforehand. And also - how would I get this working in Firefox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying fancy plugins, why not use a page break?

```
@media print {
  .print {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this in my css file but no luck. Could you please elaborate more what I should be doing?

Comment: [It works for me](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t5r3B/show/light/). Perhaps post some more of your code that's not working?

Comment: @ChristianVarga this doesn't work in Firefox. Actually prints everything on the first page. And one blank page follows

Comment: @JackWatson The code in my answer works, end of story. Before telling people their code doesn't work, you **must always check to ensure that you've implemented it correctly, and that you haven't got any other code interfering with it**. If you have an issue, then ask a new question and post the relevant code. For reference, here is a demo proving that this code has the expected behaviour (tested and confirmed working in Firefox 35): http://christianvarga.com/page-break-after-demo.html

Comment: Obviously I was talking about your [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t5r3B/show/light/). That full-screen version does not  work (anymore). I though this was the correct implementation since you provided me with it. Possibly the fiddle itself changed since you posted... Thank you for the new demo